# C++ Code used in MATLAB code

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

I have a MATLAB code and its using a C++ code.

When I try to build it using MATLAB Coder i am getting an error

Undefined function or variable 'nameOfC++file'.

How do I include / define it before building ?

PS : The matlab code works without defining this C++ file beforehand.

EDIT

How it is called

```
r = mlist(d, p);
```

I have two files, mlist.cpp and mlist.dll

Comment: If the answer below is not sufficient, it would be helpful to have: a snippet of the MATLAB code showing how the C++ code is being used, an example of how you are calling the `codegen` command, and the MATLAB Coder options you are using

Comment: If you see step (4) below, to call a C++ function `mlist` you should use `coder.ceval('mlist',...)` rather than just calling it directly by name like a MATLAB function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions to get things started:

1. Configure MATLAB Coder to generate C++ code to ensure consistent compilation and linking:

   ```
   cfg = coder.config('lib');
   cfg.TargetLang = 'C++';
   codegen -config cfg ...
   ```
2. Include the needed header(s). In your MATLAB code for code generation use:

   ```
   function y = example(x)
   %#codegen
   coder.cinclude('a_header.h');
   coder.cinclude('<a_system_header>');
   ```
3. If necessary, add include paths to the config object, `cfg`:

   ```
   cfg.CustomInclude = '/directory/with/headers /other/directory';
   ```
4. Call your external function(s) using `coder.ceval`:

   ```
   function y = example(x)
   %#codegen
   coder.cinclude('a_header.h');
   coder.cinclude('<a_system_header>');
   % Assume y is a double scalar. Change this to match the return type
   % of someExternalFunction
   y = 0;
   y = coder.ceval('someExternalFunction',x);
   ```
5. Pass any necessary C++ source files (`.cpp`), object files (`.o, .obj`), or libraries (`.a, .so, .lib, .dylib` etc.) to the codegen command:

   ```
   codegen -config cfg matlab_function_name source.cpp library.so ...
   ```

The documentation on [external code integration](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/custom-c-c-code-integration.html) shows other techniques for encapsulating dependencies on external code. Using these allows you to specify the necessary libraries, external source code, compiler flags, and other options from your MATLAB code being passed to MATLAB Coder.

That means that your code becomes self-contained so that the config object need not be modified and the call to `codegen` need not include the source files, object files, and libraries.